# Code rendered as text when placed after a list

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, code-formatting

I have some problems formatting code on so. If i use only 4 spaces in the code snipped in this post: [SO-Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28303159/2630261), the code will not be formatted as code.

I think it has some thing to do with the list (1, 2, 3), but i've made break between the code and the list.

Is there i bug right now?

Comment: Not a bug, this is `status-bydesign` due to markdown.

Comment: You're right, this helps: `<!-- -->`... Sorry...

Comment: pinging @shadowwizard

Comment: @random do you get notified? (OP sorry, just testing a theory here)